# Robes in Harry Potter movies

Tags: harry-potter

What happened to the robes in the Harry Potter movies? In the first couple of movies they wore their robes all the time, but by the end of the movie series there was little to no use of robes by the main cast, even thought they should have been wearing them the majority of the time.

Comment: They still wear them during classes, we just start following them *out* of classes more, where they're not required.

Comment: Out-of-universe, apparently *PoA* director Alfonso Cuaron wanted to show the characters' personalities through their clothes

Comment: By the end of the series they were engaged in full-time warfare. Perhaps robes weren't the most practical choice for battle! ;)

Comment: @Slytherincess you gotta die with style.

Comment: @Voldemort -- Please let us know where the Dark Lord buys his threads!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do students wear muggle clothing while not in classes at Hogwarts (like they do in the films)?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144484/do-students-wear-muggle-clothing-while-not-in-classes-at-hogwarts-like-they-do)

Comment: @ibid Im asking why they DONT wear robes in the movies specificly, which is answered by a quote from a movie director. the other question is asking IN THE BOOKS do they every not wear robes, no dupe in site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Jason Baker**'s comment is correct.

> Cuarón also made the characters feel a bit more contemporary via their wardrobe. In the previous films, the students had worn school uniforms and robes the majority of the time; in *Azkaban*, there was a shift. The young characters were now seen in normal, everyday clothes as a further reflection of their personalities and maturation. Too, they could individualize their uniforms a bit
>   <sub>*Harry Potter: From Page to Screen: The Complete Filmmaking Journey* by Bob McCabe - Page 104 - *Prisoner of Azkaban* analysis</sub>

Comment: And this is where i gave up all hope on the movies. :(

Comment: @Himarm - Why? I love the *Harry Potter* movies! Draco looks good in Prada ;)

Comment: in my opinion he ruined the look of the wizarding world, even in later books harry was still wearing the hand me down clothes from the durslys, if he had nice slacks, and button up shirts why is he still wearing jeans that don't fit. I hate when people take artistic "license" to completely step all over what is already set in stone, movie 3 really turned me off to the rest of the movies. But thats just me and i know tons of people loved the movies anyway, im just a purist. I know the females especially liked the movies due to Draco :P

Comment: I liked Draco in Prada too. I just had to hug him.

Comment: @Himarm No no, the females especially liked the movies due to Cedric. (Speaking for myself only, I especially liked the movies due to Wood … no pun necessarily intended.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- I see what you did there! Our pug dog is named after Oliver Wood :D And, no, it's definitely Draco who brings the girls to the yard. J.K. Rowling finds this a very disturbing trend.

Comment: @Slytherincess why nobody talks about Tom? He was explicitly described as very handsome...... ;)

Comment: @Voldemort -- Yeah, yeah, [we know all about your "hug"!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rAzjEDIyEI) **NSFW** Direct link to YouTube. (I am compelled to point people to this vid whenever remotely possible. Because I'm like three or something ...)

Comment: @Voldemort - and that's how bad fanfics start

Answer (score 2):

They mainly stopped wearing robes in the movies because I think that they tried to investigate in their spare time (ie the weekends, because otherwise they would have their normal classes)- so essentially they didn't exactly stop wearing robes, I was just that they didn't have to.